Maven build failing to execute goal for scala-maven-plugin after updating project from Java 8 to Java 17
I am updating my java project from Java 8 to Java 17. So I migrated all the packages and class from Java EE to Jakarta EE. For the same reason, I found that some dependencies/plugins also needs to be updated to the latest versions.
One such plugin that I updated is like this:
<plugin>
   <groupId>net.alchim31.maven</groupId>
   <artifactId>scala-maven-plugin</artifactId>
   <version>4.9.2</version>
   <executions>
     <execution>
       <id>scala-compile-first</id>
       <phase>process-resources</phase>
       <goals>
         <goal>add-source</goal>
         <goal>compile</goal>
       </goals>
     </execution>
     <execution>
       <id>scala-test-compile</id>
       <phase>process-test-resources</phase>
       <goals>
         <goal>testCompile</goal>
       </goals>
     </execution>
   </executions>
   <configuration>
     <scalaVersion>2.13.14</scalaVersion>
     <jvmArgs>
       <jvmArg>-Xms64m</jvmArg>
       <jvmArg>-Xmx1024m</jvmArg>
       <jvmArg>-Xss2m</jvmArg>
       <jvmArg>-XX:+TieredCompilation</jvmArg>
       <jvmArg>-XX:TieredStopAtLevel=1</jvmArg>
     </jvmArgs>
   </configuration>
</plugin> 

When I build my module with this plugin, then it fails with the following error:
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 02:19 min
[INFO] Finished at: 2024-11-21T14:02:00+05:30
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal net.alchim31.maven:scala-maven-plugin:4.9.2:compile (scala-compile-first) on project d_model: Execution scala-compile-first of goal net.alchim31.maven:scala-maven-plugin:4.9.2:compile failed: org.apache.commons.exec.ExecuteException: Process exited with an error: -1 (Exit value: -1) -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal net.alchim31.maven:scala-maven-plugin:4.9.2:compile (scala-compile-first) on project d_model: Execution scala-compile-first of goal net.alchim31.maven:scala-maven-plugin:4.9.2:compile failed: org.apache.commons.exec.ExecuteException: Process exited with an error: -1 (Exit value: -1)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:213)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:154)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:146)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:954)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:288)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:192)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:568)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:356)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:47)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.PluginExecutionException: Execution scala-compile-first of goal net.alchim31.maven:scala-maven-plugin:4.9.2:compile failed: org.apache.commons.exec.ExecuteException: Process exited with an error: -1 (Exit value: -1)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:208)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:154)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:146)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:954)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:288)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:192)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:568)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:356)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:47)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.commons.exec.ExecuteException: Process exited with an error: -1 (Exit value: -1)
    at sbt_inc.SbtIncrementalCompilers.lambda$makeForkedProcess$0 (SbtIncrementalCompilers.java:179)
    at scala_maven.ScalaCompilerSupport.incrementalCompile (ScalaCompilerSupport.java:325)
    at scala_maven.ScalaCompilerSupport.compile (ScalaCompilerSupport.java:119)
    at scala_maven.ScalaCompilerSupport.doExecute (ScalaCompilerSupport.java:86)
    at scala_maven.ScalaMojoSupport.execute (ScalaMojoSupport.java:310)
    at scala_maven.ScalaCompileMojo.execute (ScalaCompileMojo.java:108)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:208)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:154)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:146)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:954)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:288)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:192)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:568)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:356)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:47)
Caused by: org.apache.commons.exec.ExecuteException: Process exited with an error: -1 (Exit value: -1)
    at org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecutor.executeInternal (DefaultExecutor.java:355)
    at org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecutor.execute (DefaultExecutor.java:253)
    at org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecutor.execute (DefaultExecutor.java:236)
    at scala_maven_executions.Fork.run (Fork.java:93)
    at sbt_inc.SbtIncrementalCompilers.lambda$makeForkedProcess$0 (SbtIncrementalCompilers.java:138)
    at scala_maven.ScalaCompilerSupport.incrementalCompile (ScalaCompilerSupport.java:325)
    at scala_maven.ScalaCompilerSupport.compile (ScalaCompilerSupport.java:119)
    at scala_maven.ScalaCompilerSupport.doExecute (ScalaCompilerSupport.java:86)
    at scala_maven.ScalaMojoSupport.execute (ScalaMojoSupport.java:310)
    at scala_maven.ScalaCompileMojo.execute (ScalaCompileMojo.java:108)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:208)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:154)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:146)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:954)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:288)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:192)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:568)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:356)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:47)

Most of the errors are related to the following:

not found: value perfTrack
object TimeIt is not a member of package

I have also tried a few lower version of the same plugin and still errors are coming.

Run the maven command with the -e switch and check the stack trace.

@seenukarthi - I have added complete stack trace after using -e switch. Please check.

I think you also need to check the output before [INFO] BUILD FAILURE. As an aside, upgrading from Java 8 to Java 17 doesn't actually require you to upgrade from Java EE to Jakarta EE, those are two separate things.

Not sure what scala version you were using before, but Java 8 is compatible with scala 2.13.0, but in your pom.xml you have 2.13.14. Going from Java 8 to 17 could bring some unexpected problems. Also I don't know what are the dependencies of your project, or with just this config you shared is enough to reproduce the issue. As @MarkRotteveel pointed, you should check what is the error before [INFO] BUILD FAILURE. Another thing I would try first, is to go from Java 8 to 11. Maybe that would bring some issues that should be solved first to go to Java 11.

@sjain  the stacktrace is useless, the exception is raised because the compilation of your code failed. The important part is what is before [INFO] BUILD FAILURE . And you filter the output you reported with 1. & 2.
The way classpath is managed evolved between Java 8 & Java 17, and your error seems to be related to your dependencies & import. Are perfTrack and TimeIt defined/used into your code ? I suggest you search about those error message and how to fix it with scala.
